# Prefer not to manually pass the Authorization header after logging in to the Azure APIM developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have integrated APIs into API Management and implemented security measures by leveraging the Azure AD B2C identity provider, we have configured Azure AD B2C by creating a new Azure AD B2C tenant and setting up a user flow within it.

- Subsequently, we utilize the developer portal to access these APIs. To access the Developer portal.
- Upon successfully logging in to the developer portal using Azure AD B2C, we can access its features.
- **However, we aim to streamline the process by eliminating the need to manually include an authorization header when accessing the APIs post-login, given that we are already authenticated within the developer portal using Azure AD B2C.**
- Our objective is to have the token obtained during the developer portal login automatically included in the header for API requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the need of passing the subscription key in header by unchecking subscription required option.

[image]

By doing so, you can access the APIs without passing the subscription key in authorization header post logging in to developer portal.

[image]

[image]